# What does this RSB instruction do?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to figure out what does this ARM assembly line does:

```
RSB r1, r2, r3, LSL #1
```

I am referring to RSB description from keil page but this example does not quite fit: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289891932.htm
I would appreciate all help.

Comment: What part is it that you have problems with?

Comment: I cannot match the example as it has to many arguments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The RSB instruction is a Reverse SuBtract without carry.
The documentation indicates the syntax:

```
RSB{S}{cond} {Rd}, Rn, Operand2
```

The following usage can then be explained:

```
RSB r1, r2, r3, LSL #1
```

1. `r3, LSL #1` is Operand2 → r3 register logical left-shifted by 1 bit
2. r2 is Rn
3. r1 is Rd

So the operation uses r1, r2 and r3 registers as follows: `r1 = (r3 << 1) - r2`

Answer (score 2):

The instruction `RSB r1, r2, r3, LSL #1` shifts the contents of `r3` left by one place, subtracts `r2` and stores the result in `r1` without setting flags. In pseudocode, it does this:

```
r1 = r3 + r3 - r2
```

Note that the third operand is a *flexible operand* comprising `r3, LSL #1`. See [this page](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289851539.htm) for more details.